# Inserting and updating records at the same time

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-update, sql-insert

I have got the following Postgres table:

```
create table test (
    id serial, 
    contract varchar, 
    amount int, 
    aggregated int, 
    is_aggregate int
);
```

```
insert into test (contract, amount, aggregated) 
values ('abc', 100, 0), 
       ('abc', 200, 0), 
       ('xyz',  50, 0), 
       ('xyz',  60, 0);
```

| id | contract | amount | aggregated | is_aggregate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 100 | 0 |  |
| 2 | abc | 200 | 0 |  |
| 3 | xyz | 50 | 0 |  |
| 4 | xyz | 60 | 0 |  |

I'm trying to write an SQL statement that inserts an aggregate row on a per-contract basis, the result therefore should be this:

| id | contract | amount | aggregated | is_aggregate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 100 | 1 |  |
| 2 | abc | 200 | 1 |  |
| 3 | xyz | 50 | 1 |  |
| 4 | xyz | 60 | 1 |  |
| 5 | abc | 300 |  | 1 |
| 6 | xyz | 110 |  | 1 |

Because new rows are being added from another data source continuously, inserting of the aggregated rows and setting 'aggregated' to 1 in the rows that have been aggregated needs to happen in one go to avoid a concurrency issue.

I have tried several approaches, but I have come only this far:

```
INSERT INTO test (contract, amount, aggregated, is_aggregate)
SELECT contract,
       SUM(amount) AS sum_amount,
       1,
       1
FROM test
WHERE aggregated IS NULL 
   OR aggregated = 0
GROUP BY contract
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This inserts the aggregated rows but I can't figure out how to include a clause to update 'aggregated' to 1 for the rows that have been aggregated.

EDITED:

After several 'recondensations' the data would look like this:

| id | contract | amount | aggregated | is_aggregate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 100 | 1 |  |
| 2 | abc | 200 | 1 |  |
| 3 | xyz | 50 | 1 |  |
| 4 | xyz | 60 | 1 |  |
| 5 | abc | 300 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | xyz | 110 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | abc | 20 | 1 |  |
| 8 | abc | 30 | 1 |  |
| 9 | xyz | 70 | 1 |  |
| 10 | xyz | 80 | 1 |  |
| 11 | abc | 50 | 1 | 1 |
| 12 | xyz | 150 | 1 | 1 |
| 13 | abc | 350 |  | 1 |
| 14 | xyz | 260 |  | 1 |

... where ids 11 and 12 are again aggregations of the first run (like ids 5 and 6 before) and ids 13 and 14 are aggregations of the previous aggregation run (i. e. ids 5 and 11 as well as ids 6 and 12 respectively). Aggregations of the last run can be determined by their having 'aggregated' = NULL

Note: There are additional 'time' columns by which the aggregation level of each row can be determined for use in business logic further down the road. These columns have been omitted here for the sake of brevity.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It makes little sense to store a value that continuously gets changed. Maybe it's better to compute that value when you need it with a view, should be a fast operation nonetheless. Yet if you want to go forward with your idea, you could make it with a trigger that automatically updates your aggregate everytime a new record is inserted in the table.

Comment: There isn't only one aggregate per each group of contracts, but several ones as time progresses. As long as new basic rows haven't been aggregated I am including those in my further calculations. More importantly even: The aggregates will get aggregated themselves after a period of time. So the data overall becomes condensed over and over. This is due to the business model that I need to adhere to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having data points and aggregated data points in the same table is not an ideal design pattern, it would be better to separate them into two tables.

## One table

If you still want to use only one table then you can use the code below.

### With created_at filtering

Add a `timestamp` column called `created_at` with a default value of `NOW()`. Note that the value of `NOW()` does not change within a transaction in Postgres and it also has read consistency (snapshot isolation) which prevents rows inserted/modified by other processes after the start of this transaction to be included in this transaction.

```
-- Start a transaction
BEGIN;

-- Aggregate
INSERT INTO test (contract, amount, aggregated, is_aggregate)
SELECT contract,
       SUM(amount),
       NULL,
       1
FROM test
WHERE aggregated IS NULL
    OR aggregated = 0
GROUP BY contract
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

-- Mark aggregated rows as aggregated
UPDATE test
SET aggregated = 1
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM test
    WHERE (aggregated IS NULL
        OR aggregated = 0)
        AND created_at <> NOW()
    GROUP BY contract
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);

-- Commit the transaction
COMMIT;
```

### With explicit row locking

Add a `boolean` column called `is_locked` with a default value of `NULL`. This is due to the aggregation criteria returns different rows before and after the aggregation. An alternative could be to use the timestamp of the inserted rows to filter them out in the final update, but I'm not sure what columns are available since the table definition is partial.

This code is not parallel safe - run only one aggregation process at any given time.

```
-- Start a transaction
BEGIN;

-- Lock the rows you want to aggregate
UPDATE test
SET is_locked = TRUE
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM test
    WHERE is_locked IS NULL
      AND (aggregated IS NULL OR aggregated = 0)
      AND contract IN (
        SELECT contract
        FROM test
        WHERE is_locked IS NULL
          AND (aggregated IS NULL OR aggregated = 0)
        GROUP BY contract
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      )
);

-- Insert the data from the locked rows
INSERT INTO test (contract, amount, aggregated, is_aggregate)
SELECT contract,
       SUM(amount) AS sum_amount,
       NULL,
       1
FROM test
WHERE is_locked = TRUE
GROUP BY contract;

-- Update the aggregated column to set it to 1 for the locked rows
-- and remove the locks
UPDATE test
SET aggregated = 1,
    is_locked = NULL
WHERE is_locked = TRUE;

-- Commit the transaction
COMMIT;
```

### Two tables

If you want to use a separate aggregation table then see below.

Add a timestamp of the INSERT to the test table and use that timestamp for aggregation purposes.

**Conceptual solution proposal below. The exact syntax depends on which database engine you are using.**

The modified test table definition:

```
 create table test (
    id serial, 
    contract varchar, 
    amount int, 
    created_at timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

The new aggretation table:

```
create table test_agg (
    contract varchar, 
    amount int, 
    aggregated_to timestamp
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_agg_contract_uq ON test_agg (contract);
```

The modified SQL statement which INSERTS a row if none exists or UPDATES an existing row in the aggregation table.

```
INSERT INTO test_agg (contract, amount, aggregated_to)
SELECT t.contract,
       SUM(t.amount),
       MAX(t.created_at)
FROM test t,
LEFT OUTER JOIN test_agg ta ON ta.contract = t.contract
WHERE
    ta.aggregated_to IS NULL
    OR t.created_at > ta.aggregated_to
GROUP BY t.contract
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    amount = amount + VALUES(amount),
    aggregated_to = VALUES(aggregated_to);
```

Comment: I can't work with a separate table though, because the dataset needs to become more and more condensed over time. I.e. adding an aggregate row for the 100 basic rows that exist now, then next day adding an aggregate for the next 100 basic rows. Next week adding an aggregate for the 10 aggregates that have been added during the entire week and so on. So the condensing needs to happen within the same table (recursively, if you will) or else I would end up with an indefinite number of aggregation tables.

Comment: You can’t perform an insert and update in the same SQL statement, you would need two separate statements. If you wrap them in a transaction then you’ll ensure consistency

Comment: @Westcoaster Ok I understand. An alternative aggregation pattern is to aggregate per day, week, month, year in different aggregation tables (or in one aggregation table with a column indicating the aggregation level per row) then select from the appropriate table/rows depending on what info is needed.

Comment: @NickW MySQL and PostgreSQL allow this. Other major database engines use the MERGE command. That is why I strated that the answer is conceptual since I did not know which database engine the OP is using.

Comment: @j.d.o. your answer appears to be inserting into a separate table whereas my comment was regarding the questionner’s need to use a single table (regardless of the general view that this is not a good design pattern, which I agree with). I don’t know how a MERGE statement would work given these requirements as the “source” data is different depending on whether the record is an aggregated or not

Comment: @NickW Ok I understand.

Comment: @j.d.o. funnily enough Stackoverflow seems to have skipped the first paragraph of my original question in which I stated that I am using Postgres. Would you know about a way how to achieve this in a TRANSACTION or using MERGE?

Comment: @NickW and j.d.o.: The design pattern I chose takes into account that there are no predefined time periods for which data needs to aggregated. So the objective here is rather condensing and recondensing data recursivly which cannot be done by adding several other tables.

Comment: @Westcoaster Thanks for the update. Can you show how you want the data to look like after it has been recondensed a few times?

Comment: @j.d.o. Sure, I just updated my original question accordingly.

Comment: @Westcoaster Based on the sample data you added then I provided an updated single table solution proposal.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, just wrap the INSERT and UPDATE statements in a transaction. Once you’ve read the documentation about transactions and tried this, if you are still having issues then update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write and ask a specific question

Comment: @j.d.o. Just checked the solution with explicit record locking. This gives me the error that 'id' needs to be present in the GROUP BY clause. If I add it, though, the statement doesn't produce any aggregated rows. I would have looked into this further, but it's getting a bit late here :-)

Comment: @NickW The solution j.d.o. has provided already uses a transaction, so I can't quite see how I could come up with an even more specific question.

Comment: @Westcoaster Sorry - updated now.

Comment: @j.d.o. Works now, thanks for your help! I have accepted your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @Westcoaster You're welcome :)